# JQuery/CSS Menu wont float over fixed div on ipad

Tags: jquery, html, css, ipad

I have been working on a website that has a fixed top div with a simple dropdown menu within and a fixed left div below. If you hover over 'places to stay' in IE or FF it works perfectly but when you view it on an ipad the menu sub items appear under the fixed left div. I have tried various z-index's but i cant get it to function on the ipad correctly.

Can anyone help me?

i have coded a simple version of it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/LBv8f/

Ignore this bit. SO wouldnt let me post with only a link to jsf but there is too much code to post in here..

```
$(document).ready(function ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to move `#left-container` before `#top-nav-container` to compensate with fixed position.

Working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LBv8f/1/) (tested on Ipad)

Answer (score -1):

There is no concept of hover on ipad, so obviously  hover wont work on iPad. That said since, you have used positions you can use the media queries for ipad to position the menu as ou wish on an iPad.

```
@media (max-width:767px) {
  // css for ipad potrait mode
}


@media (max-width:979px) {
  // css for ipad landscape mode
}
```